# Como puedo deshabilitar(eliminar, quitar) el Identity en mi tabla

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio-2017

Es posible que pueda deshabilitar (eliminar, quitar) el identity mediante un script en SQL server 2014, la imagen que adjunto es una captura en Visual Estudio, donde hago comparación de tablas, las cual me tiene que quedar igual la primera a la segunda.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1):

Es imposible quitar la propiedad de IDENTITY de una columna. Para hacerlo, se tiene que eliminar la columna y crear una nueva con el mismo nombre. El mismo caso es para cuando se quiere agregar una columna IDENTITY. Sin embargo, no es recomendable hacerlo más que en casos muy particulares que hayan sido evaluados.

Si se está haciendo una comparación, dependiendo de la herramienta se podría decir que se omita esa propiedad de la comparación.

Comment: Mi plan era en un principio crean un tabla temporal, enviar información de la tabla original a la temporal, eliminar la original, y crear otra tabla original sin el Identity, y por ultimo, pasar la información de la tabla temporal a la tabla original nueva. Hasta ahí okey, cuando hice este script, me dio un error y fue las FK. 
Lo solucione haciendo que SQL haga ese trabajo de generar el script, y para eso solo tuve que cambiar un valor y un clic

Answer (score 0):

Si lo que estás intentando es migrar información de una tabla a otra y quieres que los campos de identity queden iguales puedes utilizar este escript:

SET IDENTITY_INSERT [NombreTabla2] ON

INSERT INTO [NombreTabla2] SELECT * FROM [NombreTabla1]

SET IDENTITY_INSERT [NombreTabla2] OFF

Comment: Esta no me funcionó, creí que si lo haría.